# jquery-3.5.1.js:4055 error DataTables Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema usando DataTables dentro de una modal bootstrap que debería mostrar un Query SQL con un SELECT no mas, necesito que pueda imprimirse en excel o algún otro formato pero estoy recibiendo un error en consola que dice: "DataTables Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined" y frente a esa linea se ve "jquery-3.5.1.js:4055" entonces asumo que ese debe ser el problema.

Como necesito exportar los resultados como un formato, encontré esto en Datatables

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Y es lo que trato de hacer.

Estuve leyendo en varias paginas y aquí también y parece que el problema es el orden de como están las dependencias, pero he intentado de varias maneras y no funciona, entonces no estoy seguro cual podrá ser el problema.

Estas son mis dependencias:

```
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap-4.5.0-dist/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-Bfad6CLCknfcloXFOyFnlgtENryhrpZCe29RTifKEixXQZ38WheV+i/6YWSzkz3V" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/datatables.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Buttons-1.6.2/js/buttons.bootstrap4.js"></script>
        <script src="js/DataTables-1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="js/JSZip-2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pdfmake-0.1.36/pdfmake.js"></script>
        <script src="js/pdfmake-0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Esta es la tabla dentro de la Modal

```
 <table id="tabla_a_mostrar"></table>
```

Esta es la función en el mismo archivo donde debe mostrarse la tabla (modal)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tabla_a_mostrar').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
        
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Y esta es la tabla que se genera para el SELECT:

```
$tabla="";

if ($result) {
    $data = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
    if ($data === true)  {
        while ($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $table=$table.'<tr>
            <td>'.$data['ID'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['NOMBRE'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['APELLIDO'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['numero1'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['numero2'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['MOVIL'].'</td>
            <td>'.$data['MRETIR'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
}
    sqlsrv_close($conn);

    echo '<table class="table table-stripped">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Número 1</th>
    <th>Número 2</th>
    <th>Movil</th>
    <th>Retirado?</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>'.$tabla.'
    </tbody>';
```

Eso es todo lo que tengo realmente... alguien puede ayudarme con este inconveniente? he tratado de resolverlo como por 2 días y no lo he logrado

Gracias!

Comment: La tabla no tiene ID, por favor edita la pregunta para poner exactamente cómo estás creando la tabla y cómo pretendes activar _DataTable_

Comment: La tabla si tiene ID, dice "tabla_a_mostrar" , después de las dependencias está

Comment: Entonces algo estás haciendo mal, porque en PHP tienes: `echo '<table class="table table-stripped">...'` donde no se ve ID. Debo insistir en que modifiques la pregunta para ver cómo es que llega la tabla al DOM.

Comment: Porque eso es una clase de Bootstrap, así he hecho varios CRUD en este proyecto sin problema entonces no es que sea por ahí el problema 

Comment: Asumo que tienes dos tablas, una con ID y otra con clase, o bien, tienes una tabla con ID y dentro una con clase, resultando en un HTML mal formado y, en cualquiera de los dos casos, no se podrá activar _DataTable_. En fin, tú crees que el problema no es por ahí, ¿qué se le va a hacer?

Comment: Pues, el Datatable normal, solo con paginación funciona sin ningún problema, el que no funciona es este con los botones... es una pregunta similar aquí 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454203/jquery-datatables-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined

Y pues hasta ahora no han logrado tampoco solucionar ese mismo problema :/ pero bueno, gracias por la intención Triby

Answer (score 0):

Intenta crear el encabezado de la table en el siguiente formato (incluyendo `<tr></tr>` al iniciar y finalizar `thead`:

```
echo '<table class="table table-stripped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellido</th>
<th>Número 1</th>
<th>Número 2</th>
<th>Movil</th>
<th>Retirado?</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>'.$tabla.'
</tbody>';
```

Comment: Lo intenté pero nope, aunque fue una muy buena observación